Datahub actions getting failed for hello_world action, giving PipelineConfig validation error
I'm trying to follow datahub-actions quick start https://datahubproject.io/docs/actions/
but when i do datahub actions -c hello_world.py i'm getting below error
[2024-04-22 22:33:35,602] INFO     {datahub_actions.cli.actions:80} - DataHub Actions version: 0.0.15
Failed to instantiate Actions Pipeline using config hello_world: 5 validation errors for PipelineConfig
filter
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'name': 'hello_world', '...{'type': 'hello_world'}}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.7/v/missing
transform
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'name': 'hello_world', '...{'type': 'hello_world'}}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.7/v/missing
action.config
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'type': 'hello_world'}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.7/v/missing
datahub
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'name': 'hello_world', '...{'type': 'hello_world'}}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.7/v/missing
options
  Field required [type=missing, input_value={'name': 'hello_world', '...{'type': 'hello_world'}}, input_type=dict]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.7/v/missing


can you share your recipe yaml config?

This issue was because of higher version of pydantic.
this issue was originated because datahub actions says it required > 1.15, however it doesn't work with version 2.
This should be fixed in upcoming releases of datahub actions, if someone is using older version downgrade to pydantic <2 version
